# Polling application untill condintions are met in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, api, task, polling

I have to build a service using Java and SpringBoot which will be responsible for polling an application via API till the conditions are met. So I'm sending POST request and the app has to do something. Then I'm sending GET request towards this app and fetching the data. I'm checking if the task is done. If not, I need to send this GET request one more time eg. every 10 seconds. If analysis is done, then I should stop polling. I've tried to use schedulers but there is a problem with checking conditions. Runnable object cannot return any value so I can't cancel the task in a proper moment. The second thing is that I can have more than one task at the same time to polling. Do you have any idea how I can resolve my problem?

Comment: Do you want to have separated threads for each task? Do you have a table where you can track the requests?

Comment: I can store information about requests in Data Base. Regarding the threads, it's hard to say. I don't know how many requests I can expect at the same time. But probably I can have more than one thread. Or maybe I should limit the number of requests to be handled and rest of them keep at the queue?

Comment: You say that you will send POST requests, but how are these requests initiated? Do you receive the request from another application, or you invoke POST based on some different business logic? I'm asking this because if you expose your own api and than pass it further i don't think it's a good  idea to do the get pooling on the same thread as you may end up with way to many threads active in the same time.

Comment: Yes, I will receive a request from another application, then I have to modify that request a bit and  make a new POST request towards the third app. So my application will be in the middle of that chain.

Comment: Ok, what is the purpose of the GET interrogation? Do you have to notify them back in any way? I assume they don't wait until the processing is finished.

Comment: If GET shows that task is done, then I have to create and send another GET request and results send to other services. So it looks like App A sends request to my App. I build a POST request and send it to App B. Based on response from App B, I'm sending toward this app GET requests until conditions are met (task is done). Then I'm sending another GET to App B and results can be passed further to other services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking at two options:

1. Each time when sending a POST save details of the request in a table. Using a @Scheduled annotation, once at x secons, you can query the table and call GET api for all requests which are not processed yet. Once a request is processed you can update the status in the table so it won't be picked up next time.
2. Each time after sending a POST request, using ThreadPoolExecutor add a thread which will poll GET api.
   Edit: having the full picture now, i think you should persist the request details for both options, because if something will go wrong you need to have the details saved somewhere for a future retry.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try to implement that solution.